# window.location with hash returns to the top of the page

Tags: javascript, html

I have two pop-ups, one for confirmation and the other for notification. I use

1-`onclick = 'window.location.href = "#confirmation"'` to open confirmation box, then I use

2-`window.location = "mypage.php#"`  after user confirms the action, in order to clear browser link from ..../mypage.php#confirmation hash, then finally I use

3-`window.location = "#notification"`. in order to open notification pop-up.

This action returns user to the top of the page. I wonder if there is any way that I can clear browser link from #confirmation hash so that I would skip second step that makes user turn back to the top of the page.

Comment: Why not just skip it and instead of clearing `window.location` go straight to `#notification` ?

Comment: There's absolutely a way, but **how** are you clearing it? Through JavaScript? Through PHP?

Comment: Because it will add hashes like this: mypage.php/#confirmation#notification. Thats what I experienced.

Comment: Then you are adding the hash incorrectly, `location.hash = "foo"`

Comment: Through JavaScript

Comment: @Ahmet I'm not sure what you're doing but I just tried it in my browser `window.location.href = '#test';` adds `#test` to my url, calling it again with `window.location.href = '#test2;` doesn't add another hash but replaces current `#test` with `#test2`

Comment: I don't know why it happens but probably because final window.location is run in the function and the function runs while the page is at mypage.php#confirmation state.

Comment: Gonna try location.hash right away.

Comment: location.hash instead of window.location is my answer. Thanks.